# How can I create a grid of elements with solid borders?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a div with a solid border. I have a good start but having some trouble getting the alignment right and getting the lines working. Below is an image of the requested HTML

[image: Word Doc Image]

So far I think I'm some what close with my HTML but my two top lines do not match and I cant get the vertical line in.

code:

```html
<div style="width:60%;border:solid">
  <div style="width:45%; display: inline-block;">
   <div style="margin-left:5px;">
    Domestic Shipping and Handling<br>
    <hr style="width: 5px;"/><br>
    $25..01 to $50.00..add $7.95 <br>
    $50.01 to $75.00...add $11.95 <br>
    $75.01 to $100.00...add $13.95 <br>
    $100.01 to $150.00...add $17.95 <br>
    $150.01 to $200.00 .. add $19.95 <br>
    200.01 &#8211; above.. add $23.95
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 8%; display: inline-block;"><hr style="width: 1px; height: 100px;"></div>  
  <div style="width:45%; display: inline-block;">
   Canada, AK, HI, PR Shipping and Handling<br>
   <hr style="width: 5px;"/><br>
   $.01-$25.00.. add $14.95<br>
   $25.01 - $50.00.add $15.95<br>
   $50.01 to $75.00...add $18..95<br>
   $75.01 to $100.00...add $20.95<br>
   $100.01 to $150.00..add $25.95<br>
   $150.01 to $200.00..add $28.95<br>
   $200.01 to above....add $32.95            
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is what my HTML looks like on the web page currently:
[image: HTML On Webpage]

I'm currently missing the vertical line, top headers are not aligning and bottom texts are not aligning. Originally this was using a table which is fine but now we want it to be responsive and to use div's. I also can not use css. I would prefer to use css personally but that request was denied.

Comment: Few thoughts... you are using CSS; divs don't make something responsive; a table can be responsive; tabular data should be in tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably build this using html tables. [See here for further help.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics)

```html
<style>
table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Domestic Shipping and Handling</th>
    <th>Canada, AK, HI, PR Shipping and Handling</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $25..01 to $50.00..add $7.95 </td>
    <td> $.01-$25.00.. add $14.95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$50.01 to $75.00...add $11.95</td>
    <td>$25.01 - $50.00.add $15.95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$75.01 to $100.00...add $13.95</td>
    <td>$50.01 to $75.00...add $18..95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$100.01 to $150.00...add $17.95</td>
    <td>$75.01 to $100.00...add $20.95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$150.01 to $200.00 .. add $19.95</td>
    <td>$100.01 to $150.00..add $25.95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>200.01 &#8211; above.. add $23.95</td>
    <td>$150.01 to $200.00..add $28.95</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your post. I used your code and adjusted it a little to get my answer but your code is better then mine. Here is my code after adjustments:

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
   <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;">Domestic Shipping and Handling</th>
   <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding:5px;">Canada, AK, HI, PR Shipping and Handling</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;"> $25..01 to $50.00..add $7.95 </td>
   <td style="padding:5px;"> $.01-$25.00.. add $14.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;">$50.01 to $75.00...add $11.95</td>
   <td style="padding:5px;">$25.01 - $50.00.add $15.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;">$75.01 to $100.00...add $13.95</td>
   <td style="padding:5px;">$50.01 to $75.00...add $18..95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;">$100.01 to $150.00...add $17.95</td>
   <td style="padding:5px;">$75.01 to $100.00...add $20.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;">$150.01 to $200.00 .. add $19.95</td>
   <td style="padding:5px;">$100.01 to $150.00..add $25.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td style="border-right: 1px solid black; padding:5px;">200.01 &#8211; above.. add $23.95</td>
   <td style="padding:5px;">$150.01 to $200.00..add $28.95</td>
    </tr>
  </table style="border: 1px solid black;">
```

Hope it helps someone else. I added padding as well to this because the other version was really close together and hard to read.